# jQuery selecting elements by name

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

I have the following html:

```
<td valign="top" align="left"> <input style="width:250px;" name="men_url" type="text" /></td>


<td valign="top" align="left"> 
<select name="men_page">
 <option value="">Wybierz stronę</option>
 <option value="index.php?page=8">O firmie</option>
 <option value="index.php?page=9">Referencje</option>

</select>
</td>
```

and two corresponding jQuery selectors:

```
$("select[name='men_page']")
```

and

```
$("input[name='men_url']")
```

The first one works great, the second one returns nothing. What might be wrong here?

Especially alert($("input[name='men_url'").name); displays "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

also, there's no "name" property. Use `$(..).attr('name')` instead.

// Pozdrawiam ;) / ["greetings", in polish] ;)

Comment: Actually there is. In pure JS :) But you have to use: `$('.selector')[0].name` (that [0] thing is mandatory, either you use ID or Class selector)

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you. Code that works: $("[name='men_url']")[0].name
I feel sorry for my mistake that caused wrong answer to be upvoted 8 times and the good one only by me.

Answer (score 8):

The 2nd one is missing the closing `]`

Comment: This was only a mistake while copying. Sorry for that. The problem is different.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$("input[name='men_url']")
```